# i Cant Select file in my own browser in android

Tags: android, html, file, select, browser

I have created an android app for a simple website view (Using webview)  but I can't select file   using

I am trying to make a app which completely load the website made using php

Comment: Please show the code and explain what have you've tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use your Web view in this way .

```
        webview =(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings=webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        WebSettings webSettings=webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

Comment: webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.loadUrl("https://domain/");
  but it also cant select file

Comment: it also cant select file

Comment: can you select file at php side ?